# django's class based views static files

Tags: django

I am having some issues loading my css and javascript files when using generic class based views.

The folder structure is like this.

```
- app1
  - views.py ect
  - templates
    - app1.html
- static
  - static
    - css
    - base.css
```

app1.html:

```
<link href="/static/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

views.py:

```
class ClientList(ListView):
    model = Client
    template_name = 'app1.html'
```

I tried moving the static files inside the app but it still cant find them

If you need anymore info please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need additional `static` dir inside the root `static`:

```
- app1
  - views.py
  - templates
    - app1.html
- static
  - css
    - base.css
```

So in the template you can refer the `base.css` as:

```
{% static 'css/base.css' %}
```

And don't forget to set the [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) setting.

If you want to put static files into the app dir the the layout could be like this:

```
- app1
  - views.py
  - templates
    - app1.html
  - static
    - css
      - base.css
```

In this case the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting is not required.

Note that if you put static files (or templates) into the app dir then it is a good practice to add a dir with the app's name to prevent filename clash with another app:

```
- app1
  - views.py
  - templates
    - app1
      - base.html
  - static
    - app1
      - css
        - base.css
```

And then in the template:

```
{% static 'app1/css/base.css' %}
```